# WPF MVVM: Call method from control from inside attached usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I have custom control (FooCtrl) and it has 4 DependencyProperties (Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4).

```
public partical class FooCtrl : UserControl { 
    // ... 

    // Q1:
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Q1Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Q1", typeof(UIElement), typeof(FooCtrl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public UIElement Q1
    {
      get { return (UIElement)GetValue(Q1Property); }
      set { SetValue(Q1Property, value); }
    }

    // Q2:
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Q2Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Q2", typeof(UIElement), typeof(FooCtrl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    public UIElement Q2
    {
      get { return (UIElement)GetValue(Q2Property); }
      set { SetValue(Q2Property, value); }
    }

    // Q3:
    // ....

    // Q4:
    // ....


    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I use the control like:

```
<my:FooCtrl>
<my:FooCtrl.Q1>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ...}" /> 
</my:FooCtrl.Q1>
<my:FooCtrl.Q2>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ...}" /> 
</my:FooCtrl.Q2>
<my:FooCtrl.Q3>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ...}" /> 
</my:FooCtrl.Q3>
<my:FooCtrl.Q4>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ...}" /> 
</my:FooCtrl.Q4>
```

I can add 4 usercontrols to the FooCtrl Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4 properties.
Via the method "DoSomething()" on the FooCtrl I can change animate Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4:

```
myFooCtrl.DoSomething();
```

**How can I access the method from FooCtrl "DoSomething()" from inside my usercontrols (which are attached via Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)?**
*E.g. if I bind a usercontrol to a contentcontrol of Q1 - Q4 and the usercontrol contains a button "Do it!" how can this access the "DoSomething()" from FooCtrl so that it gets executed?*

If it helps: I'm also using Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 0):

If `DoSomething()` is truly only view based, in that it just drives an animation, and that animation doesn't represent any kind of model state, then you can use a [RoutedCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Your `FooControl` can expose a custom routed command, and your "Do it!" buttons can bind to it. Routed commands will travel up and down the visual tree until they find something that has a matching command binding. In your case they will bubble up the tree until they hit your `FooControl`, which will then execute the command.

Another option would be to have FooControl expose [Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the buttons can bind to. Much like stuff inside a `Grid` can use `Grid.Row` to tell their parent where they want to live.

If the animations DO represent some kind of model state, then the animations should be driven from the ViewModel bindings.